# How to call a function through event handlers in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm making a little word search program. So when the user clicks the `Search` button, he is told how many times the word he searched for occurred. To do this I have a function `listToDict` I have previously used which creates a `dictionary<string, int>` where `string` is a word and `int` is the number of times that word occurs. I then created a `word_search` method which is the following

```
public void word_search(Dictionary<string, int> myDict)
        {

            if (myDict.ContainsKey(wordSearch.Text))
            {
                int value = myDict[wordSearch.Text];
                wordSearchResult.Text = "Number of occurrences:  " + value;
            }
            else
            {
                wordSearchResult.Text = "Cannot find this word sorry";
            }
        }
```

This `word_search` function takes the dictionary I created in `listToDict` and searches for how many times the user input word occurs. For this I have to call `word_search(myDict)` inside of `listToDict` where it is created. The problem I am now facing is how do I make it so that when the user clicks the search button, these functions are called?

E.g Something like this ? But obviously this doesn't work because `occurrenceDict` does not exist here, it exists inside of `listToDict`

```
public void wordSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            word_search(occurrenceDict);
        }
```

Comment: You need to declare a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) that can store the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to make the `occurrenceDict` as field or property so that it can used to search the value :

```
public YourClass
{  
  Dictionary<string, int> MyDictionary {get; set;}


   public void wordSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if(MyDictionary != null )
        {
           word_search(MyDictionary );
        }
     }
}
```